# How to build mutation_map for batch_mutate in Perl and Cassandra 1.0

Tags: perl, insert, cassandra, thrift, batch-processing

The Cassandra Thrift [example site](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ThriftExamples#Perl) still refers to the "batch_insert" command, which apparently has been deprecated.  With Cassandra 1.0 one is supposed to use batch_mutate which requires a $mutation_map to be passed.  Does anybody have a working example on how to build up the map?  According to the [API documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API) it has to look like this:

```
batch_mutate(map<binary, map<string, list<Mutation>>> mutation_map, ConsistencyLevel consistency_level)
```

However I seem to be unable to figure out how to build up the map correctly and I can't find anything describing how to do this in Perl without any of the wrapper modules, e.g. Net::Cassandra.

Any help, example, link is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you can tell, the map has several layers:

- The outer layer, which has row keys as the keys for the map
- The middle layer, which has column family names as the keys for the map
- The inner layer, which is a list of Mutation objects

Essentially, row key => column family => list of mutations.

Each of the Mutation objects in the inner layer should one of its two properties set:

- For insertions: column_or_supercolumn (a ColumnOrSuperColumn object)
- For deletions: deletion (a Deletion object)

If you're inserting several columns in the same row/cf, you need to have a Mutation object for each one of them.

[Cassandra::Simple](https://github.com/fmgoncalves/p5-cassandra-simple) seems to [use batch_mutate in several places](https://github.com/fmgoncalves/p5-cassandra-simple/blob/master/lib/Cassandra/Simple.pm#L863).  I'd recommend trying to use it and improve it rather than build a new client.  The maintainer is quite active with the project.

Comment: Tyler, this library is extremely promising and I can create keyspaces, CFs just fine. However, if I try to run the example on inserts I am seeing this: "$VAR1 = 'Bit::Vector::new_Dec(): input string syntax error at /usr/local/share/perl5/Thrift/BinaryProtocol.pm line 203."  ... Would you have an idea what might be causing this?  Incompatible libraries?

Comment: It sounds like that might be a problem with the Thrift perl library itself.  I'm not a perl guy, so I can't help much.  Check with the maintainer of that library to see if he's seen it before or can help.